# How to install Node.js version 16.x.x in a Debian based image (Dockerfile)? (why so hard?)

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, apt-get, debian-based, debian-buster

**Date:** **Tuesday October 5th, 2021**

**Node 10.x** was released on **2018-04-24** (but that's the default version when using apt-get)

---

I have needs to have both Python and Node.js installed in running container.  I can get the latest version of python in a container using:

`FROM python:alpine`

or

`FROM python:buster`    <== Debian based

---

How do I get the latest version of node.js (16.10.0) installed on Debian (in a Docker container)

Whe I do this:

```
FROM python:buster

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
    nodejs npm
```

I get these versions of node:

**node: 10.24.0**

**npm   5.8.0**

and when run in the container give a long statement about no longer being unsupported.

What's up with the package repo that 'apt-get' pulls from, that it will not install later versions of node (14.x or greater)?

---

**If I pull from:**

```
FROM python:alpine

and include these lines
RUN apk -v --no-cache --update add \
    nodejs-current npm
```

---

I will get node **16.x** version, which makes it easy.  I don't have to do anything else.

Is there something equivalent for **python:buster** (Debian based)

I would really like a one or two liner in my **Dockerfile** and not a pages of instructions with a dozen commands to simply get node in the image.

---

I would appreciate any tested/proven reply.  I am sure a number of others have the same question.  Other stackoverflow articles on this subject are convoluted and do not provide the simple solution I am hoping to find that is available with pytyon:alpine

There is a reason I need **python:debian** and cannot use python:alpine in this one use case, otherwise I would chose the latter.

---

Is there a way some how to get a package repo maintainers attention to show me how to get a recent version (**14..16**), into the apt-get repository?

It appears many people are having issues with this.

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
FROM python:buster

RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get install -y \
    nodejs npm

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x | bash - && \
 apt-get install -y nodejs
```